# How to optimize this piece of code? [Processing inside nested for loops]

Tags: java, performance, optimization, runtime

```
for (int i = 0,len=size-2; i < len; i++) {
            for (int j = 1,leng = size-1; j < leng; j++) {
                for (int k = 2; k < size; k++) {
                    if (i < j && j < k) {
                        sum = sum + Math.floor((a[i] + a[j] + a[k]) /    (a[i] * a[j] * a[k]));
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

I need this piece of code to run in atleast half of the current running time.Here, the array 'a' is of the type double. I am taking inputs via the reader class. How to achieve a faster run time?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this code?

Comment: @MichaelPickett I have to perform summation on a triplet of the array. Code is doing its job. I just need to atleast half the runtime.

Comment: It looks to me like this code is doing the same thing multiple times. Most notably, every `i` loop summates `j` and `k` minus 1 location.

Comment: @MichaelPickett I didn't understand that. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Treycos There are N elements in an array. I have to take summation of triplets x,y,z such that 0<=x<y<z<=N-1.

Comment: and the summation should be done on the formula in the code for each such x,y,z

Comment: I am glad, I made it clearer to you@Treycos

Comment: How big can (a[i] + a[j] + a[k]) / (a[i] * a[j] * a[k]) be? Can it be negative? How big can N be?

Comment: 1≤N≤3⋅10^5 @AntonínLejsek

Answer (score 1):

Your nested loops do nothing but iterate unless the condition `i < j && j < k` is satisfied.  But the middle and inner loops start their iterations at the same initial value every time, regardless of the values of the outer loop indexes.  For example, when `i` is `5`, the middle loop still starts at `1` and the inner one still starts at `2`, even though they can *know* that they will not perform any useful work for those values.

Start each loop iterating from a more useful point.  You will save much useless index arithmetic and many vain index comparisons.  In fact, if you do it properly then you shouldn't need to perform any index comparisons at all.

Details, such as they are, are left as an exercise.  I've probably offered too much help already.

Comment: Yes you have. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite `1/(x*y*z)`as `1*(1/x)*(1/y)*(1/z)`. Multiplying is faster than dividing. You can precalculate array of reciprocal values as `ra[i] = 1/a[i]`. There can be further optimizations, but it depends on what values there can be, You did not answer that question.

Answer (score 0):

With this code there will not be any need of an if statement:
`x` is always inferior to `y` which is always inferior to `z`

```
for (int x = 0; x < size - 2; x++)
    for(int y = x + 1; y < size - 1; y++)
        for(int z = y + 1; z < size; z++)
            sum += Math.floor((a[x] + a[y] + a[z]) / (a[x] * a[y] * a[z]));
```

Comment: Thanks. But unfortunately, this didn't had any change on the runtime.

Comment: The operation in the Math.floor() might be taking like 99% of the runtime, thats the only thing you can improve

Comment: I See no other way :(

Comment: Mhm... why do you need the Math.floor()?, Try without it and check the exec time to see if thats the pb

Comment: the problem is that the floor operator is part of the summation function.

Comment: There's no way of making this faster then

Comment: It's not a surprise that there was no change in runtime. Java compiler optimizes pretty aggressively so even a badly written loop will run quite fast after optimization.

Comment: Yup, this program was supposed to make it faster by around twice, didn't know that